# spatial reference

Tags: windows-phone-7, reference, spatial, arcgis

I'm new to Windows Phone 7 development here.
I have recently downloaded and tried out the Arcgis sample Map and it gives me this error after changing the TiledMapserverlayer's URL.

```
Invalid spatial reference. Spatial reference must match map's spatial reference. Clear the map layers collection prior to changing the spatial reference.
```

.xaml

```
            <esri:GraphicsLayer ID="MyGraphicsLayer">
                <esri:GraphicsLayer.Graphics>
                    <esri:Graphic Symbol="{StaticResource RedMarkerSymbol}">
                        <esriGeometry:MapPoint X="11560518.5450925" Y="153495.271364825">


                        </esriGeometry:MapPoint>
                    </esri:Graphic>
                </esri:GraphicsLayer.Graphics>
            </esri:GraphicsLayer>

            <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="MyLayer" 
                Url="http://www.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/basemap/MapServer" />
        </esri:Map>
```

.cs

```
    public partial class Map : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    GeoCoordinateWatcher _watcher;
    Graphic _graphicLocation;
    private static ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Projection.WebMercator mercator =
      new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Projection.WebMercator();
    bool initialLoad = true;

    public Map()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _graphicLocation = (MyMap.Layers["MyGraphicsLayer"] as GraphicsLayer).Graphics[0];

        _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
        _watcher.MovementThreshold = 20;

        _watcher.StatusChanged += watcher_StatusChanged;
        _watcher.PositionChanged += watcher_PositionChanged;

        // Start data acquisition
        _watcher.Start();
    }

    void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
                // The location service is disabled or unsupported.
                // Alert the user
                StatusTextBlock.Text = "Location is unsupported on this device";
                break;
            case GeoPositionStatus.Initializing:
                // The location service is initializing.
                // Disable the Start Location button
                StatusTextBlock.Text = "Initializing location service";
                break;
            case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:
                // The location service is working, but it cannot get location data
                // Alert the user and enable the Stop Location button
                StatusTextBlock.Text = "Data unavailable";
                break;
            case GeoPositionStatus.Ready:
                // The location service is working and is receiving location data
                // Show the current position and enable the Stop Location button
                StatusTextBlock.Text = "Ready - retrieving data";
                break;
        }
    }

    void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        _graphicLocation.Geometry = mercator.FromGeographic(new MapPoint(e.Position.Location.Longitude, e.Position.Location.Latitude));

        // Use horizontal accuracy (returned in meters) to zoom to the location
        if (initialLoad)
        {
            Envelope rect = new Envelope(
                (_graphicLocation.Geometry as MapPoint).X - (e.Position.Location.HorizontalAccuracy / 2),
                (_graphicLocation.Geometry as MapPoint).Y - (e.Position.Location.HorizontalAccuracy / 2),
                (_graphicLocation.Geometry as MapPoint).X + (e.Position.Location.HorizontalAccuracy / 2),
                (_graphicLocation.Geometry as MapPoint).Y + (e.Position.Location.HorizontalAccuracy / 2));

            MyMap.ZoomTo(rect.Expand(20));

            initialLoad = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MyMap.PanTo(_graphicLocation.Geometry);
        }
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _watcher.Stop();
    }}
```

I have tried many solution such as adding in the wkid but it doesn't work.
I have been having this error for very long. Can someone please help!
Thanks

Comment: graphics that you add to a map must have the same spatial reference as the map.  If you changed the URL, did you change to a map that has a different spatial reference?  That may have caused the error.  One possible solution is to reproject the coordinates of the graphics to the spatial reference of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you shouldn't be mixing SpatialReferences. Calling Map.Pan, Zoom of changing Extent to an unprojected geometry with an SRef different than the Map's SRef will result in an exception being thrown. When the GPS position changes you are trying to move the Map which is of a diff SRef which causes the exception. You won't have that problem if you project the GPS point first. Use the GeometryService for that. Btw take a look at the API's GpsLayer in their toolkit cause it can save a huge amount of the code you wrote manually above. Also set a ProjectionService on it and things should just work for you.

Cheers :)